# Developing app logic for WP7 without emulator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, compact-framework

I'm working in constrained environment (win7 under VirtualBox), and everything works excellent, except emulator (debug on real phone is OK). But I'm new to Visual Studio and .NET, and would like to develop all logic (at least interaction with web, algorithms, data models) in separate library (to test it against simple console or WPF application).

But here problems come — WP7 library uses special solution (and all projects by default are built against .NET Framework 4, when phone runs with .NET CF 3.7, why?). How I should setup IDE, to build crossplatform (I mean desktop/windows phone 7) library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An acquaintance of mine suggested to use [Portable Library Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981), which allows creation portable library for multiple target platforms (xbox, winphone7, silverlight, etc) without recompilation. Looks very promising.

Answer (score 2):

You can create parallel projects (one for desktop, one for phone) and add your c# files to one of them and link them in the other project.

To add a link to a file instead of copying it follow these steps:
Right click on the project => add existing item -> Select the file -> click the drop down arrow next to the "Add" button and chose "Add as Link".

To solve any incompatibility you can define a conditional compilation symbol like PHONE  and wrap your incompatible code in:

```
#if PHONE
 //phone code
#else
 //desktop code
#endif
```

The downside is after you add a new code file in a project you need to link it from the corespondent project of the other platform.

I don't think there is a easier way of doing this.

Comment: I don't plan to write any desktop-dependent code, so no hardcoded switches. I should just copy files? Is it possible to do with same files, just using different project files?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant: In the project where you don't have the file do: Right click on the project -> add existing item -> navigate to the cs file and then instead of Add button click on the drop down arrow and select "Add As Link".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MVVM pattern to develop your viewmodels (the business logic) in one assembly, then when you are ready for the UI, you can create a WP7 project and create the views inside that project, referencing the view models in the first project.

This would allow you to unit test and develop all your logic first, then just create the views and bind to the appropriate properties on the appropriate viewmodels.

MVVM was designed to be able to develop like this, so it works really well IMHO.